# Need help to get the full innertext of a WebElement using Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit, specflow

How can I get the full innertext from a WebElement, right now it is only getting part of it.

```html
       <ul class="pagination-list">
        <li class="page-to-left icon-bold-set-left page-to-left-disabled" ng-class="{ &#39;page-to-left-disabled&#39; : !HabilitaPaginaAnterior }" ng-click="PaginaAnterior()"></li>
        <li class="page-count ng-binding">1 - 10 de 24</li>
        <li class="page-to-right icon-bold-set-right" ng-class="{ &#39;page-to-left-disabled&#39; : !HabilitaProximaPagina }" ng-click="ProximaPagina()"></li>
    </ul>
```

And my selenium code:

```c#
 public void EntaoAPaginacaoMostrando()
        {
            string validaPaginacaoString;
            IWebElement ControllerPaginacao = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@ng-controller='PaginacaoController']"));
            IWebElement validaPaginacaoString = controllerPaginacao.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='page-count ng-binding']")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");         

            Console.WriteLine("TestData: o texto de paginação é: " + validaPaginacaoString);


        }
```

Running this code, my result always is "1 - 10 de" for some reason I can´t get the "24".

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

After extensive search I´ve found that the app I´m testing uses AngularJS so the  "24" takes some time to be loaded.

The right aproach would be use Protractor that has a built-in method to wait for angular to load.

Using a Thread sleep works too because it waits for angular to load the content. But you know, using sleep is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
...GetAttribute("innerHTML").Text
```

Comment: I´ve tried and it keeps just giving me "1 - 10 de"  without the "24".

Comment: how about just .Text and remove the GetAttribute(...) ?  I don't think you need that last part to get the text you want.

Comment: Still the same result, tried with  .Text instead of .GetAttribute